# gnome-shell 3.34 missing ExtensionUtils.extension property

Tags: linux, gnome, gnome-shell-extensions, gjs

I've written a GNOME shell extension for `gnome3.30-3.32` using:

```
const ExtensionUtils = imports.misc.extensionUtils;
...

ExtensionSystem.disableExtension(ExtensionUtils.extensions['extension-uuid'].uuid);
```

Updating to 3.34 version, `ExtensionUtils` does not provide the `'extension'` property, and I don't know to find the documentation about it.

How can I fix the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you're looking for, the map of loaded extensions, is also a part of the `ExtensionSystem` module, whereas the `ExtensionUtils` module is mostly utilities for extension authors like GSettings and Gettext helpers.

The functions you are looking for are a part of the class `ExtensionManager` in 3.34+. You can get the `ExtensionManager` *instance* from the `Main` import:

```js
// >= 3.34
const Main = imports.ui.main;
const ExtensionManager = Main.extensionManager;

ExtensionManager.disableExtension(uuid);

// <= 3.32
const ExtensionSystem = imports.misc.extensionSystem;

ExtensionSystem.disableExtension(uuid);


// Handling both versions
const Config = imports.misc.config;

if (Config.PACKAGE_VERSION.split('.')[1] >= 34) {
    let manager = imports.ui.main.extensionManager;

    manager.disableExtension(uuid);
} else {
    let extSystem = imports.misc.extensionSystem;

    extSystem.disableExtension(uuid);
}
```

Sources:

- https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/blob/master/js/misc/extensionUtils.js
- https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/blob/master/js/ui/extensionSystem.js

You can use the branch selector on the left of the GitLab page to select the version, or the history button on the right to view a list of changes to a given file.

Comment: Issue fixed! if (extensions._enabledExtensions.includes(uuid)) {
                   extensions.disableExtension(uuid);
               } else {
                   extensions.enableExtension(uuid);